How to generate single PDF file from multiple byte array in Java using iText
I am having 3 separate byte array for 3 pages. Now I want to merged into a single PDF file.
What I have tried so far
byte[] page1;
byte[] page2;
byte[] page3;

try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filePath)) {
    os.write(page1);
    os.write(page2);
    os.write(page3);
} catch (Exception e) {
}

Above code generating the PDF but not showing any data in the generated PDF.
Not able to understand why its not showing any information in the pdf.
But if I generated pdf only one byte like below code then pdf generated with content.
try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filePath)) {
    os.write(page1);
} catch (Exception e) {
}

Any help appreciate.

"I am having 3 separate byte array for 3 pages." - What exactly do those byte arrays contain? Images? TeX files? Videos? PDF files? Texts? ...?

@mkl Its pdf file

@KJ can you please share how can I do this

I think we're overcomplicating. if these are in-memory representations of PDF files, why not just use the Merge functionality?
